# How can I determine which examples RSpec will run

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to execute some code before an arbitrary RSpec test is run, but only in cases where the example groups to be tested are either in a specific directory or carry a specific tag.

For example, if I have the following groups:

```
## spec/file_one.rb
describe "Spec One - A group which needs the external app running", :external => true do

describe "Spec Two - A group which does not need the external app running" do

## spec/file_two.rb
describe "Spec Three - A group which does NOT need the external app running" do

## spec/always_run/file_three.rb
describe "Spec Four - A group which does need the external app running"
```

Then I want the code to be executed *only* when a test run contains Spec One or Spec Four.

This is relatively easy to do when I can rely on the filename, but harder when relying on the tag.  How can I check what files examples will be run and then check their tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just have a support setup like this:

```
PID_FILE = File.join(Rails.root, "tmp", "pids", "external.pid")

def read_pid
  return nil unless File.exists? PID_FILE
  File.open(PID_FILE).read.strip
end

def write_pid(pid)
  File.open(PID_FILE, "w") {|f| f.print pid }
end

def external_running?
  # Some test to see if the external app is running here
  begin
    !!Process.getpgid(read_pid)
  rescue
    false
  end
end

def start_external
  unless external_running?
    write_pid spawn("./run_server")        
    # Maybe some wait loop here for the external service to boot up
  end
end

def stop_external
  Process.kill read_pid if external_running?
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  before(:each) do |example|
    start_external if example.metadata[:external]
  end

  after(:suite) do
    stop_external
  end
end
```

Each test tagged with `:external` would attempt to start the external process if it's not already started. Thus, the first time you run a test that needs it, the process would be booted. If no tests with the tag are run, the process is never booted. The suite then cleans up after itself by terminating the process as a part of the shutdown process.

This way, you don't have to pre-process the test list, your tests aren't interdependent, and your external app is automatically cleaned up after. If the external app is running before the test suite gets a chance to invoke it, it will read the pid file and use the existing instance.

Rather than relying on `metadata[:external]` you could parse the full name of the example and determine if it needs the external app for a more "magical" setup, but that's kind of smelly to me; example descriptions are for humans, not for the spec suite to parse.

Comment: The code isn't external specifically, but the answer is just as relevant, thanks!